# Doubt in Computing $\iint_S x dxdy$ where $S: x^2+y^2=1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Computing $\iint_S x dxdy$ where $S: x^2+y^2=1$

In text book it is directly written as 0. Any shortcut for this?

I did it in following way.

Given integral = $\iint_{r= 0to1, \theta : 0 to 2 \pi} r \cos \theta r dr d\theta = 0$

Comment: Under the map $(x,y) \mapsto (-x,y)$, the domain $S$ is invariant while the integrand picks up a minus sign.

Comment: I think you probably mean $x^2+y^2 \leq 1$, or the integral is zero since the area of $S$ is zero.

Comment: @achillehui can u pls elaborate? Even (-x,-y) (x,-y) also do not change in S....

Comment: You can see that this is integral is zero directly by symmetry, i.e. if you split your integration domain (the disk $S$) into two halves (w.r.t. the $y$-axis in this case), then the integrals over these two halves are equal and of opposite sign, so they cancel out.